# Meaning of しれし on this haiku?

Tags: grammar, conjugations, classical-japanese

寝たなりは桜としれしけさの雪-一茶

Is it related to 知る？

Or the auxiliary  し

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though I can't give a precise interpretation of the whole haiku, a natural reading for the part in question should be as follows:

しれし is 知れ + し, where 知れ is 連用形 (bold) of

> [知る](https://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%97%E3%82%8B)
> 自動詞ラ行下二段活用 
> 活用 れ／**れ**／る／るる／るれ／れよ
>
> 知られる。

and し is 連体形 of [き](https://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%8D), which indicates a past tense (i.e. roughly equivalent to the modern た).

Thus, literally, 桜としれし means 桜と知られた (known to be a cherry tree).

Comment: That reminds me of similarly constructed 愛されし or 選ばれし

Comment: Since the past-recollective き in the し form would be the 連体形 or adnominal, what is the 体言 or nominal that it applies to?  Syntactically it would seem at first glance to be けさの雪 -- indicating that the morning's snow was (mis-)recognized as cherry blossoms as the poet was going to sleep.  Is that parsing correct?

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi So would this roughly be, "the snow, that fell as I slept, revealed as cherry blossoms"?  taking extreme liberty here in translating "しれし", but we do use metaphors of "seeing" to mean to "know".

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi It should be けさの雪, but as [this](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%8D-471819) says it can be without modifiee. ( if 連体形「し」が、係結びの場合でなくて文の終わりに用いられることがある happens regardless of 係り結び)

Comment: @A.Ellett I guess it is verbosely like "what was seen as cherry blossoms in my (half) sleep turned out to be snow this morning". I am not sure though.